# Can anyone give me a function to calculate date and time in python ? I m in WINDOWS 10

Tags: python, date, time, dayofweek

Please can anyone provide me function for time,date & day in python

just like time = time()
and time = "##:##:##" # is replaced with current time in my laptop

And date = date()
and date = "####/##/##"

And day = day()
and day = "sun/mon/tue/wed/etc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess as sp
import datetime as dt

def time():
    t = dt.datetime.now()
    h = str(int(t.strftime("%H")))
    m = str(int(t.strftime("%M")))
    s = str(int(t.strftime("%S")))
    ampm = " AM "
    h = int(h)
    if h > 12:
        h = h - 12
        ampm = " PM "
    h =str(h)
    return str(h) + ":" + t.strftime("%M:%S") + " " + ampm

def out(command,he):
    result = he.run(command, stdout=he.PIPE, stderr=he.PIPE, universal_newlines=False, shell=True)
    d = result.stdout
    outp = d
    f = d.find(b'\r')
    if f>0:
        outp = d[0:f]
        outp = str(outp)
        outp = outp[2:len(outp)-1]
    return outp

def date(han):
    myot = out("echo %date%",han)
    myot = myot[4:len(myot)]
    return myot

def day(he):
    myot = out("echo %date%",he)
    myot = myot[0:3]
    if myot == "Wed":
        myot = myot + "nes"
    elif myot == "Thu":
        myot = myot + "rs"
    elif myot == "Sat":
        myot = myot + "ur"
    elif myot == "Tue":
        myot = myot + "s"
    myot = myot + "day"
    return myot

date = date(sp)
day = day(sp)
time = time()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a timestamp with the current time and date you can use:

```
import datetime

timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
```

You can then use that `timestamp` object to get the information you need with:

- `timestamp.year`
- `timestamp.month`
- `timestamp.day`
- `timestamp.hour`
- `timestamp.minute`
- `timestamp.second`
- `timestamp.weekday()` - This is a method and so you need the parenthesis

If you want to understand a bit more what you are doing you can read the python datetime documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html